# How to post array data in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I post to array json like `{"productId":[1, 2, 3]}`.

I got errors 
**`Cannot assign "[<Product: Short Sleeve>, <Product: Short Sleeve>, <Product: Short Sleeve>]": "FittingCartItem.productId" must be a "Product" instance.`**

I already try add `many=True` argument in get_serializer function.
I don't know how solve this problem...

**serializers.py**

```
class ItemListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(source='productId', read_only=True)
    memberId = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), write_only=True, required=False)
    productId = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), write_only=True, many=True)
    is_live = serializers.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FittingCartItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer
    queryest= FittingCartItem.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                            headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**models.py**

```
class FittingCartItem(models.Model):
    memberId = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fittingcarts')
    productId = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your ```models.py```?

Comment: What's the error with many=True ? Surely it isn't the same message as the one pasted

Comment: Add your models.I can see the issue in the serializer but without your models, i cannot suggest a solution.

Comment: @EnthusiastMartin  i'm so sorry for being late, I went on a short summer vacation

Comment: @cagrias  i'm so sorry for being late, I went on a short summer vacation

Comment: @iamdifferent  it is not clear what you want to achieve. You cannot send list of product id because your FittingCartItem can have only one productId ( per one cart item )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yout serializer, you want your product to be serialized by ProductSerializer, which causes your serializer to expect "Product" instances instead of productIds in your JSON input.

What you need is to tell yout serializer to expect products as productIds, which is possible by using PrimaryKeyRelatedField.

You need to delete:

```py
product = ProductSerializer(source='productId', read_only=True)
```

This will solve your problem because DRF automatically acts ForeignKeys in models as PrimaryKeyRrlatedFields. But if productId was not defined as ForeignKey, but instead ManyToMany relation etc. You need to add it as below:

```py
productId = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```